# Generate sparse vector

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have two lists. One with indexes (set obviously) and one with values. Is it possible to convert them in a numpy array with fixed size efficiently?

```
indexes = [1,2,6,7] 
values = [0.2,0.5,0.6,0.2]
size = 10
```

What I want to output is:

```
print(magic_func(indexes,values,size))
array(0,0.2,0.5,0,0,
      0,0.6,0.2,0,0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy in two lines, if you want:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: arr = np.zeros(size)

In [3]: arr[indexes] = values

In [4]: arr
Out[4]: array([ 0. ,  0.2,  0.5,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0.6,  0.2,  0. ,  0. ])
```

Comment: You can wrap it in a function if that makes it any better? `In [2]: def magic_func(indices, values, size): arr = np.zeros(10); arr[indices]
 = values; return arr`